# PPTP VPN DNS delay

Tags: macos, pptp

When I connect a PPTP VPN on Lion, it takes several minutes for DNS resolution to actually switch over to the addresses that come back over PTPP. Is there some parameter somewhere what would speed up this process?

Here's some output from nslookup which demonstrates the oddity:

> /Users/benson/x/oap2 nslookup
> server
> Default server: 10.0.0.1
> Address: 10.0.0.1#53
> jira.basistech.net
> Server:        10.0.0.1
> Address:   10.0.0.1#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:  jira.basistech.net
> Address: 67.215.65.132

The PPTP connection DNS address is 10.1.0.50, but still opendns.com is in control here via the panera wireless, returning crap advertising pages.

Comment: I've not seen this happening with my VPN connections. I think you shoudl add some screeshots of you network configuration screens, specifically the network order, and the dns sections of the VPN connection settings

Comment: The order now is PPTP first (in the order dialog box), but the main network settings shows it second to to Wifi.

Comment: The order was the problem. Make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen this happening with my VPN connections. I think you should add some screenshots of you network configuration screens, **specifically the network order**, and the dns sections of the VPN connection settings